# Why is my font-weight only switching from normal and bold instead of following the number?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I implemented the font Inter into my website following their web site instructions: https://rsms.me/inter/download/ for Web Use.

However, I'm noticing that setting my font-weight to 100, 200, 700, 800, etc. doesn't matter, all that happens is for 600 and up my font is bold, and 500 and below my font is normal. How can I make it so the font weight is set for each number?

```css
/* IMPORTANT */
:root {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  font-feature-settings: 'liga' 1, 'calt' 1; /* fix for Chrome */
}

@supports (font-variation-settings: normal) {
  :root { font-family: InterVariable, sans-serif; }
}

.btnText {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.boldBtnText {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="btnText">
    normal
  </p>

  <p class="boldBtnText">
    bold
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you linked to the font files as described? You can point to your local version of the files. And also check you don't have any console errors.

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://rsms.me/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css">

Answer (score 0):

You left out any reference to their inter.css. If you simply add

```
@import url('https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css');
```

at the top of your CSS, you can set font-weight to any integer value between 100 and 900 and you'll get continuous variation of weights.

(Adding the `@import` line is what the other answer did, but then in that answer font-family was set to `Inter`, which means the variable font is not requested.)

Comment: Their docs claim to just do this: 

:root {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  font-feature-settings: 'liga' 1, 'calt' 1;
}
@supports (font-variation-settings: normal) {
  :root { font-family: InterVariable, sans-serif; }
}

Is this just for the basic version or something?

Comment: Their docs put a link to the inter.css file in the HTML head element. You could do that; using `@import` in the CSS is achieving the same thing. You need to do one or the other.

Comment: In CSS, `:root{ ... }` is setting font styling on the entire page to use Inter, but then `@supports (font-variation-settings: normal { ... }` is setting different font styling using InterVariable if the browser supports `font-variation-settings:normal`.

Answer (score -1):

```css
/* IMPORTANT */
@import url('https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css');
:root { font-family: Inter, sans-serif; }
  @supports (font-variation-settings: normal) {
    :root { font-family: InterVariable, sans-serif; }
  }
.btnText {
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.boldBtnText {
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="btnText">
    normal
  </p>

  <p class="boldBtnText">
    bold
  </p>
</div>
```

You can try to just import the css from your css like above. I just tested using the different font weight.